# Python 3.10 [Errono 2] No such file or directory - Python 3.10 not being recognised in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-install

I installed python3.10 on my mac. I can see it under applications but when I type python 3-- version it returns the following error.

```
MacBook-Air:~ User$ python3 -- v
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/User/v': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Python2 -- version returns with the default python 2.7.18 which is already installed with Mac OS.

Steps I've taken:

```
MacBook-Air:~ User$ alias idle="idle3" # to use python3 idle rather than 2.7
MacBook-Air:~ User$ alias python="python3" # to use python3 rather than python2.7
```

This was to map python to python 3 it worked but I still received the following error..

```
MacBook-Air:~ User$ python -- v
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/User/v': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help!

Comment: You are using wrong command, there should be no space between - - and V. Try this: python3 --version

Comment: What is `python3 -- v` meant to be doing? Do you perhaps mean `python3 --version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the command you've entered. This makes the Python interpreter think you're trying to run a script called `v`, which obviously doesn't exist.

```sh
python3 -- v
```

For checking the version, you should either:

1. Use one hyphen and a capital letter: `python -V`
2. Use two hyphens and the full word: `python --version`.

There should be no space after the hyphen.

Comment: Thank you so much! such a simple thing!! Really appreciate it!  I saw a youtube video which said to use python --v

Comment: @user18233539 Cool! These are in fact common conventions in command lines. Read more: [relevant stackexchange post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307467/what-are-good-habits-for-designing-command-line-arguments), [GNU website](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)